# Unable to upgrade to scikit-learn v0.22.1 in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Am using Anaconda 3 (conda version : 4.8.2, conda-build version : 3.18.9) - Jupyter Notebook environment with python (v3.7.4).

Am trying to upgrade scikit-learn package to 0.22.1, but am continuously encountering below error:

Command used: conda install scikit-learn=0.22.1

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- 0.22.1

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

Can someone please help me with this issue! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message hints towards an additional space in `scikit-learn=0.22.1`. But your installation command seems correct. Can you double check that again? Can you copy-paste `conda install scikit-learn=0.22.1` into your command line?

Comment: No luck! Still the same error! In fact, this error is specific to 0.22.1; If am trying any previous versions like v0.21.3, they are successfully downloaded and installed.

Comment: I was able to find at least one package: scikit-learn 0.22.1 py37h6288b17_0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where conda didn't recognized there is a newer version and just didn't update sklearn.
I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but I think it will and I suggest you try the following solutions:

1. It seems your channels are bit different then mine (I'm also using win10 64bit) Try running:

   ```
   conda config --append channels conda-forge
   conda install scikit-learn=0.22.1
   ```
2. If step 1 fails, run:

   ```
   conda update conda
   conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
   ```
3. Follow the solution in here [Cannot update python package on anaconda to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848202/cannot-update-python-package-on-anaconda-to-latest-version) (given by lucasgcb), I recommend closing all of the running conda envs first.
   If the path contains spaces don't forget to add "" around the path.

In my case solution 3 do the trick, but I got a different error than you:

```
Updating scikit-learn is constricted by

anaconda -> requires scikit-learn==0.22.1=py37h6288b17_0
```